# Some express api calls give cors errors when using React after refactoring some api calls

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I understand that this question has been asked to oblivion, but I havent been able to solve my particular issue with it.

When I started my project, I had cors error too, but after adding the following they dissapeared, until today I decided to refractore the code of an app, and it suddenly stopped working, fun fact is that the old code was working ok.:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

I have tried too

```
  app.use(cors({ 
   origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
 }));
```

But the point is, that every single api call works, except one. And even better, it works randomly, sometimes it gives a cors error and sometimes it doesnt. Thats why im lost.

I have downloaded a chrome extension `Moesif origin and cors changer` and that seems to be the only way to make it work. But its not a valid solution.

Why is this happening?

My api call is this one. As u can observe a simple call with some database manipulation and thats it, it should return a res.status of 100, but im unable to see it when using the chrome extension, and otherwise it will be ccors blocked

```
    //generate calendar
app.post('/generateCalendar', async (req, res) => {

  const userId = req.body.userId
  const yearsToLive = req.body.yearsToLive
  const registerDate = req.body.registerDate

  function filterDate(date) {
    var stringDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
    console.log("dentro del filter date")
    var result = stringDate.match(/(?:(?!T).)*/)
    return result[0];
  }

  function getWeeksToLive(death_date, birth_date) {
    //returns the weeks to live between death and birth date, rounded to upper week

    var weeks_to_live = moment(death_date).diff(moment(birth_date), 'days') / 7;
    console.log("semanas a vivir: " + Math.ceil(weeks_to_live))
    return Math.ceil(weeks_to_live);
  }


  //sets the deathDate and weeksToLive in the database
  db.query("SELECT * from users where id =" + userId).then(data => {
    var birth_date = data[0].birth_date
    var deathDate = ""
    //sets the death_date and the weeks to live
    deathDate = moment(filterDate(birth_date)).add(yearsToLive, 'years')
    db.query("UPDATE users SET death_date = '" + moment(deathDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString() + "' , weeks_to_live = '" + getWeeksToLive(deathDate, birth_date) + "' WHERE id = '" + userId + "';").then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      /*******/
      //Sets the yearsToLive and registerDate in the database
      db.query("UPDATE users SET years_to_live =  '" + yearsToLive + "' , register_date = '" + registerDate + "'  WHERE id = '" + userId + "';").then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        db.query("INSERT INTO calendar (user_id) values ('" + userId + "');").then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          // res.send(data)
          /*******/
          //Sets all the field for the calendar
          db.query("INSERT INTO calendar_field (text, rating, calendar_id, week_number) select '', 0, c.id, g.wn from calendar c join users u on u.id = c.user_id cross join generate_series(1, u.weeks_to_live) as g(wn);").then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("series generated")
            /******/
            //the lifeExpectanceSet restriction is removed and access to dashboard is granted
            db.query("UPDATE user_permissions SET life_expectancy =  'false' , dashboard = 'true'  WHERE user_id = '" + userId + "';").then(data => {
              console.log("everything generated")
              res.sendStatus(100)
              console.log(data)
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
          }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.send(err)
      })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

  })




})
```

This is the old code when it used to work, I havent really done anything apart from refactoring some stuff

```
    //generate calendar
app.post('/generateCalendar', async (req, res) => {

  const userId = req.body.userId
  const yearsToLive = req.body.yearsToLive
  const registerDate = req.body.registerDate

  function filterDate(date) {
    var stringDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
    console.log("dentro del filter date")
    var result = stringDate.match(/(?:(?!T).)*/)
    return result[0];
  }

  function getWeeksToLive(death_date, birth_date) {
    //returns the weeks to live between death and birth date, rounded to upper week

    var weeks_to_live = moment(death_date).diff(moment(birth_date), 'days') / 7;
    console.log("semanas a vivir: " + Math.ceil(weeks_to_live))
    return Math.ceil(weeks_to_live);
  }


  //sets the deathDate and weeksToLive in the database
  db.query("SELECT * from users where id =" + userId).then(data => {
    var birth_date = data[0].birth_date
    var deathDate = ""
    //sets the death_date and the weeks to live
    deathDate = moment(filterDate(birth_date)).add(yearsToLive, 'years')
    db.query("UPDATE users SET death_date = '" + moment(deathDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString() + "' , weeks_to_live = '" + getWeeksToLive(deathDate, birth_date) + "' WHERE id = '" + userId + "';").then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

  })

  //Sets the yearsToLive and registerDate in the database
  db.query("UPDATE users SET years_to_live =  '" + yearsToLive + "' , register_date = '" + registerDate + "'  WHERE id = '" + userId + "';").then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    db.query("INSERT INTO calendar (user_id) values ('" + userId + "');").then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      res.send(data)
    })
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    res.send(err)
  })

  //Sets all the field for the calendar

   db.query("INSERT INTO calendar_field (text, rating, calendar_id, week_number) select '', 0, c.id, g.wn from calendar c join users u on u.id = c.user_id cross join generate_series(1, u.weeks_to_live) as g(wn);").then(data => {
     console.log(data);
   }).catch(err => console.log(err))


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem is that res.sendStatus() is not working for some reason, I switched to res.send("string") and it does the trick